# Facebook Comment Integration in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I would like to add Social Comments to my web content portlet. For example I want to add and article and have facebook comment into it.
I've tested the plugin Social comment but its not working for me. Thank you for showing me the method.

Comment: "Social Comments" (https://www.liferay.com/de/marketplace/-/mp/application/18513329) would be exactly what I'd point you to. You say that it doesn't work for you, but give no clue what aspect of it doesn't fit what you need. How should we know?

Comment: Hi, this is not working, there no error, the portlet don't show up I changed display options on liferay-display.xml the portlet finally  showed up, but it didn't contain the described functionalists.

Comment: Did you contact the developer of the plugin? Activated commenting in Control Panel? The documentation looks like there's something to activate. And what I know of APIs like Facebook is that you'll need some API key from them.

Comment: Hi, this plugin is not supported any more, I configured well and tried to modify in the source code, but I can't find the desired functionality. As I solution I developed a template using velocity the inject facebook IFrame having the comments and like buttons. And I will develop a portlet soon for the needed job.